# Cannot delete line of XML code in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I cannot delete this piece of code in my AndroidManifest.xml. Whenever I build and run project it reappears and causes an error.

```
Error:(33, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/04/08/why-cant-edit-manifest-android-studio.html

Comment: @CommonsWare that worked! I did not notice the 'instant run' in the AndroidManifest file name.

Answer (score 0):

The following is reproduced from [my blog post from last year](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/04/08/why-cant-edit-manifest-android-studio.html) (and lightly modified to reflect changes since then):

You are using Android Studio, at least through v2.2.3, and you
are encountering [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93290) that I filed a report over two years ago. According to that issue, this is fixed in Android Studio 2.3.

What is happening is that double-clicking the error is opening up a tab
on *a* manifest. It is the wrong manifest. Rather than the
`AndroidManifest.xml` file from somewhere in `src/`, it is a generated
manifest from somewhere in `build/`. This generated manifest blends in
not only your module's manifest, but entries from the manifests of
modules and other dependencies (such as
[their `<uses-permission>` elements](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html)),
your module's `build.gradle` file, and so on. Changes you make here will
be obliterated on your next build.

When editing a manifest, make sure that it is the right manifest.